# How do I set microsoft Edge browser binary file for Selenium Remote Webdriver

Tags: microsoft-edge, binaryfiles, remotewebdriver, selenium-grid2

I am trying to execute remote webdriver tests using Selenium Grid, My node is a Windows 8 system, and I have insider version of edge installed on it. Now when I try to execute my tests, the node starts the driver service but it is not able to find the microsoft edge binary on the node.

Machine : Windows 8 
Edge Version : 77.0.235.9
binary Path :  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Beta\Application\msedge.exe
Selenium Version : 3.141.59

1. I tried to append the path to the edge executable "msedge.exe" on the node's Path variable -> did not work
2. I tried to mention the edge_binary bath in the nodeconfig.json as well, but still the executable was not found.

```
 else if (browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
                EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.107:8889/wd/hub"), options);
                return driver;
            }
```

nodeconfig.json :

```
{
"capabilities":
    [
        {
        "browserName"       :   "chrome",
        "maxInstances"      :   5,
        "seleniumProtocol"  :   "WebDriver"
        },
        {
        "browserName"       :   "firefox",
        "maxInstances"      :   5,
        "firefox_binary"    :   "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe",
        "seleniumProtocol"  :   "WebDriver",
        "acceptInsecureCerts": true, 
        "acceptSslCerts": true
        },
        {
        "browserName"       :   "internet explorer",
        "version"       :   "11",
        "maxInstances"      :   5,
        "seleniumProtocol"  :   "WebDriver"
        } ,
        {
        "browserName"       :   "MicrosoftEdge",
        "platform"      :   "WINDOWS",
        "edge_binary"       :   "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Beta\\Application\\msedge.exe",
        "version"       :   "77.0.235.9",
        "maxInstances"      :   5,
        "seleniumProtocol"  :   "WebDriver"
        } 
    ],

  "proxy"                       :   "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession"                  :   10, 
  "port"                        :   5555,
  "register"                    :   true,
  "registerCycle"               :   5000,
  "hub"                         :   "http://192.168.1.107:8889",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout"      :   5000,

  "nodePolling"                 :   5000,
  "role"                        :   "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter"  :   1000,
  "downPollingLimit"            :   2,
  "debug"                       :   false,
  "servlets"                    :   [],
  "withoutServlets"             :   [],
  "custom": {
        "webdriver.ie.driver"       :   "drivers/ie/win/IEDriverServer.exe",
    "webdriver.gecko.driver"    :   "drivers/firefox/win/geckodriver.exe",
    "webdriver.chrome.driver"   :   "drivers/chrome/win/chromedriver.exe",
    "webdriver.edge.driver"     :   "drivers/edge/win/msedgedriver.exe"
  }
}
```

How can I make the executable visible to the client trying to automate it,
EdgeOptions does not allow to set a binary path as well.

Comment: try to refer C# code example in this link and try to run it on your side to check whether it helps to solve the issue or not. Ref: https://textuploader.com/1r69p modify the code as per your on requirement.